# What quotation marks are used for the 3rd quote?

Tags: quotation-marks

I know that the nested quotes are usually punctuated as follows (British usage):

[...] and then he said: 'I will always remember Churchill's "I have nothing to offer but blood, toil, tears and sweat" as the most powerful quote to ever get me through tough times.'

**What quotation mark should be used if that is inserted into yet another quote:** eg.

Jules Cocovin gave this precise quote: '[...] and then he said: "I will always remember Churchill's #I have nothing to offer but blood, toil, tears and sweat# as the most powerful quote to ever get me through tough times."'

Please, kindly, refrain from advice regarding how I can restructure the sentence. I know how. I don't know what the 3rd level of quotation marks is in English.

Comment: ABA or BAB. Alternated single and double inverted commas. Doubtless covered on ELU before.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. Seems logical. Though sometimes there's going to be some nice clusters at the end, it seems.

Comment: Italicising can sometimes get you out of it. '... and then he said: "I will always remember Churchill's *I have nothing to offer but blood, toil, tears and sweat* as the most powerful quote to ever get me through tough times."'

Comment: @WeatherVane It could. I toyed with the idea but it was my 2nd option, as italics are used elsewhere in the text, and that would have made things difficult to read.

Comment: If you consider 'that would have made things difficult to read [/construe]' / 'Though sometimes there's going to be some nice clusters at the end, it seems' .reasons to avoid some usages (and I certainly agree), your request that people don't suggest restructuring seems infelicitous. The use of triple ... levels of inverted commas is rarely in line with the Gricean maxim of manner (essentially here, _de-clutter_).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So, would I be allowed to reduce the final cluster of inverted commas?

Comment: There is no third type of quotation mark. Repeated levels of nesting alternate between the existing two. *The man said, "Wait, did you hear that she said, 'Wait, did you hear that he said, "Wait?" ' "*

Comment: Avoid such formatting and restructure; you can't arbitrarily tinker with it. That leads to confusion.